# debug statements not showing on the debug log

Tags: apex, debugging

I have custom debug statements on the controller now which is not showing up on the debug log. I see the method getting executed and exited but i could not see anything on the debug log.

**Edited to add Code Below:**

```
 <apex:component controller="Ctrl_PK_DisplayOptions" access="public" > 

     <apex:attribute name="group" assignTo="{!sLookupGroupCode}" type="String" required="true" 

          <apex:attribute name="mode" assignTo="{!ctr_mode}" type="String" required="true" />

     <apex:attribute name="languageCode" assignTo="{!sLanguageCode}" type="String" required="true"> 

          <apex:selectList value="{!output_property}" size="1" style="{!style}">

               <apex:selectOptions value="{!lstOptions}" /> 

          </apex:selectList> 

 </apex:component>
```

I have set the debug log filter for apex to debug, visual force to info and system to debug. Is there a reason why the debug log will not show any output even though it is executing the code?

Thanks

Buyan

Comment: is this on the dev console or monitoring > debug logs. also you havent turned logging off on the apex class itself ? also worth checking if an unhandled exception is causing the debug to be unreachable - first statement in method entry ?

Comment: It greatly helps when viewing a debug log to download it from the dev console. It always seems to me that there's more detail you can read when the log has been download than when viewing it in the dev console. If you can post a section of your code that's not displaying in your log, that might help in case there's something about your debug statements that's the cause of your issue.

Comment: @crmprogdev We have a vf page which is using 2 components to display radio buttons and combo boxes on the page. The component looks up at a custom object to display value. We found that if i use the same component twice like 2 radio buttons or combo box, the debug statements will not show up at all on the log.

Comment: @crmprogdev here is the code <apex:component controller="Ctrl_PK_DisplayOptions" access="public" >
    <apex:attribute name="group" assignTo="{!sLookupGroupCode}" type="String" required="true"     <apex:attribute name="mode" assignTo="{!ctr_mode}" type="String" required="true" />
    <apex:attribute name="languageCode" assignTo="{!sLanguageCode}" type="String" required="true"> 

    <apex:selectList value="{!output_property}" size="1" style="{!style}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!lstOptions}" />
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:component>

Comment: @techtrekker Can 2 vf components using same controller make the debug statements disappear in the log? Has anybody encountered any issue like this.

Comment: Can we see the Apex code and the relevant section of the debug log?

Answer (score 3):

I just took a look at your code in my Dev Org and tried to compile it. I noticed immediately that there's a `\>` missing at the end of the 2nd line of your code. That may have been an error in your copy/paste. If that's the case, I found another problem that prevented it from compiling for me. Each of your `<axpex:attribute>` lines is missing a required field: `description="description is missing for your attribute"` as I've noted in the code below:

```
<apex:component controller="Ctrl_PK_DisplayOptions" access="public" > 

 <apex:attribute name="group" description="description is missing for your attribute" assignTo="{!sLookupGroupCode}" type="String" required="true"/>

    <apex:attribute name="mode"  description="description is missing for your attribute" assignTo="{!ctr_mode}" type="String" required="true"/>

        <apex:attribute name="languageCode"  description="description is missing for your attribute" assignTo="{!sLanguageCode}" type="String" required="true"/> 

              <apex:selectList value="{!output_property}" size="1" style="{!style}">

                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!lstOptions}">

                  </apex:selectOptions> 

              </apex:selectList>
```

More to the point to your original question, I don't see any debug statements in your code. As such, I wouldn't expect to see any debug statements in the log. Perhaps that's because the code you've posted is not the code from within the controller that calls it??